# function prototype for a two dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, function-prototypes

Im writing the function prototype for function that contains two arrays

```
void fillAndDisplay(int data[50][8], string names[50]) //prototype

fillAndDisplay(data, names); // call

void fillAndDisplay(int data[50][8], string names[50]){ // definition

}
```

The compiler doesn't like this. What am I doing wrong?

[Example of a call attempt]

```
int main()
{

    fillAndDisplay(data, names);


    return 0;

}
```

It underlines data and names and says "no instance of overload function matches the required data type.

Comment: Can we have the specific error message please? Also, what are the declarations for data and names?

Comment: Perhaps a missing semicolon at the end of your prototype declaration? You know, just before that `//prototype` comment? Otherwise, I just tested, putting the call into a `int main()` context compiles just fine. (don't tell me you tried calling you function out-of-the-blue, literally as depicted by your question)

Comment: It underlines the "int" in int main and 0 in return 0; and says expected a '}'

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi tried that it still won't work. I'm going to update the question with my code. Maybe I'm setting something up wrong

Comment: You totally screwed your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [compiles just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ac98706dae7fe58):

```
#include <string>

void fillAndDisplay(int data[50][8], std::string names[50]); //prototype

int main() {
  int data[50][8];
  std::string names[50];
  fillAndDisplay(data, names); // call

  return 0;
}

void fillAndDisplay(int data[50][8], std::string names[50]){ // definition

}
```